# Unexpected token in API Ajax Request, what's the issue?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, token

I have a document that has the below contents within it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var apiKey = "8h3wb";
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://api.centralindex.com/v1/entity/search/who?who=Starbucks&country=ie&api_key=8h3wb',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            console.dir(data);
        }

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is format in which the JSON is returned:

{"success":true,"msg":"ok","data":{"total_rows":20,"rows":[{"_id":"611068083122176","_rev":"181-78a9931ef136cbb9f61493dd7e25f435","type":"business","when":"2014-09-23 16:42:23 +00:00","country":"ie","scope":"public","trust":1,"status":{"status":"active","meta":

What could be the issue?

P.S: I am not an idiot, :(

Comment: You told jQuery to expect JSONP, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the first and the last double-quote " in your response?

EDIT:

I see your response calling the url and i think is ok.

Maybe its the &.ajax() instead of $.ajax()

Comment: Cleaned it up, that was my fault, sorry senor.